# A question on derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $w_j \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $j$.

Let $w(\lambda ) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^m {{w_j}{\lambda ^j}} $.

Is it true that,  $w'(\left| \lambda  \right|) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^m {j{w_j}{{\left( {\frac{{\bar \lambda }}{{\left| \lambda  \right|}}} \right)}^j}{\lambda ^{j - 1}}}$?

If it is'nt true, then what is $w'(\left| \lambda  \right|)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $w(z)= 1+z$. Then $w'(z)\equiv 1$. Your expression would have
$$w'(|re^{i\theta}|)=\frac{\overline{(re^{i\theta})}}{|re^{i\theta}|} = \frac{re^{-i\theta}}{r}=e^{-i\theta}$$
which is not necessarily $1$.

So, no.

What *is* true is that
$$w'(|\lambda|) = \sum_{j=1}^{m}jw_j|\lambda|^{j-1}$$
(note also that you can drop the term with $j=0$ since the coefficient $jw_j=0$).